# Sites with constantly updated info for Best Bang for your Buck components for system building?

Tags: hardware

Can anyone recommend their favorite website that maintains an up to date "best bang for your buck components to build your own pc" article. I recall coming across an excellent site where they listed the components for 3 systems (low, middle, high end) but can't recall the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest [HardForum](http://hardforum.com/) the community there is always talking about the latest and greatest hardware, they point out hardware deals and are all pretty helpful.

Comment: I'm also a fan of the [H]!

Answer (score 2):

I am a fan of [PC Part Picker](http://pcpartpicker.com/uk/). Makes it very easy to find compatible boards with different CPUs and has a lot of filter options.

Answer (score 1):

[Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com) reviews all major components of PCs. They have charts dating back years and also provide price / performance charts to rate equipment.

Answer (score 0):

This looks interesting, for benchmarks at least:

http://www.anandtech.com/bench/default.aspx?b=2